# Are there performance concerns with querying a varchar(1) column vs. a bit flag and datetime comparison?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Using MS SQL 2008, all tables contain a Status varchar(1) column that indicates "I" for inserted record, "U" for updated record, and "D" for deleted record as well as a DateCreated datetime column and a DateUpdated datetime column.

In most cases, we want to query tables for active records only and we would do something like:

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE Status <> 'D'
```

To provide a perspective on usage, this is most frequently used filter as it appears in nearly every query and multiple times when tables are joined.

We're developing a new web application and database with a focus on maximizing performance.  One proposal is to, starting with this and future projects, have the varchar(1) Status column pattern replaced with a bit like "IsDeleted" to indicate if the record was deleted or not and infer updated status from the two datetime fields.

In other words...

```
SELECT column as InsertedRecords FROM table WHERE Status = 'I' -- Rare case
SELECT column as UpdatedRecords FROM table WHERE Status = 'U' -- Rare case
SELECT column as ActiveRecords FROM table WHERE Status <> 'D'
SELECT column as DeletedRecords FROM table WHERE Status = 'D'
```

...would instead look something like...

```
SELECT column as InsertedRecords FROM table WHERE IsDeleted = 0 AND DateCreated = DateUpdated -- Rare case
SELECT column as UpdatedRecords FROM table WHERE IsDeleted = 0 AND DateCreated <> DateUpdated -- Rare case
SELECT column as ActiveRecords FROM table WHERE IsDeleted = 0
SELECT column as DeletedRecords FROM table WHERE IsDeleted = 1
```

Are there any tangible performance benefits/implications (primary around indexes and large queries) or are both implementations perfectly acceptable?  Are there any disadvantages with continuing the current pattern for consistency sake to align them with the previously created applications/databases?

Comment: Why varchar(1) instead of char(1)?

Comment: The tests I did showed no difference between the two in performance, but we aren't in a position to do actual heavy load/performance testing for another month.

Answer (score 1):

I think the's not much to lose or gain from just using a bit column instead of a char(1) column.

In terms of indexing, an index on just a bit column won't give you much value as it may have only 2 possible values: 1 and 0 (I assume your column is not nullable).

A query with `WHERE` condition `DateCreated <> DateUpdated` won't work very well as it won't be able to use indexes efficiently and will most likely behave worse than your existing char(1) field.

All in all, I think your existing solution will work better than a bit field and a date field. If you want to use numbers, you can store your values in a tinyint field instead (e.g. I = 0, U = 1, D = 2).

There's two further things that you can possibly do to improve performance:

- Create indexes based on the bit/char column and other columns depending on the queries you run (e.g. on `IsDeleted` and `DateCreated`)
- Include colums returned in `SELECT` in your index so that the query doesn't have to look up records from the table.

Comment: This makes sense.  I was more concerned about any potential red flags with either solution when querying over large amounts of data.  I do have one question: Instead of using `DateCreated <> DateUpdated`, what about `DateUpdated IS NULL` and `DateUpdated IS NOT NULL` and while leaving the DateUpdated field empty until an actual update occurs?  Would that behave better, worse or the same as `= 'I'` and `= 'U'`?

Answer (score 1):

Without going into too much detail (you can look it up yourself), other ways to improve performance over non selective data are: filtered indexes and table partitioning.

For example if you're looking for sprecific data within `WHERE Status <> 'D'` then that might benefit from a filtered index. Basically it only indexes the records you're interested in, making the index a bit smaller (and possibly faster)

Personally I prefer the I/U/D pattern over the bit pattern as to me it is 'orthogonal' and it's what I'm used to.

Also if you don't look at the deleted records much you may wish to split them off into a different partition. It's transparent to the user (they see just one table) but behind the scenes you can actually put it on a slower cheaper disk, back it up less etc. Also it knows which partition to go to and doesn't bother looking in the other (deleted) partitions.

I would also consider why you have these deleted records cluttering up this table if you rarely ever use them. Perhaps you could move them into a datawarehouse and report forom there instead.

Comment: Deleted records provide a limited undo window and get pruned.  While their life is relatively short-lived in the database, we still need to filter them out.